# How would i repeat a filecopy in visual basic?

Tags: vb.net, filecopy

I'm trying to create a program that repeatedly copies a file to test a flash drive's true size. Since overwriting a file isnt allowed, how would i name the files that go to the destination differently so that i could copy it multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

I would append your loop variable to the end of your destination file name